# Protection in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is it possible that in excel certain fields are allowed for user input and other cells are to be protected (can't edit directly)?

Example:Suppose I have 3 column.
1. On column A (Name) user can edit directly by double click.
2. On column B (id) will auto generate unique number when a data is entered into column A. User will not be able to double click on that cell.
3. On column C (gender) a drop down list.User will not be able to double click on that cell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Under format cells in the right click menu, make sure that all cells in the worksheet where you want to restrict user access are locked. This option is found under under "protection".
- Next select the cells you want the user to have acccess too, and enter the same dialog, but this time make sure that the cells aren't locked.
- Finally, turn on sheet-protection, and in the protection menu, allow the user to select unlocked cells, but not locked cells:

[image]

- Done!